# Bash scripting printf'ing an escape sequence contained in a variable

Tags: bash

Bash code:

```
yellow="\e[1;33m"
chosen_colour="${yellow}"
declare -i score=300
printf '%s %d\n' "${chosen_colour}" "${score}"
```

Result:

```
\e[1;33m 300
```

Should be:

```
300 /* in yellow */
```

---

How can I interpolate a string value containing an ANSI escape sequence into a printf statement without using either of these syntaxes:

#### Avoid 1: (works, in fact, but it's wasteful when doing a lot of `+=`s)

```
s="${yellow}"
s+="${score}"
s+=...
s+=...
s+=...
s+=...
s+=...
s+=...
s+=...
s+=...
```

#### Avoid 2: (hard to do in my case for the sheer number of variables requiring this construct)

```
printf "${yellow}${score}${a1}${a2}${a3}${a4}${a5}${a6}${a7}${a8}........."
```

---

I want to be able to pass the values to be replaced, according to a predefined FORMAT string, using the *arguments* part of the `printf` call, as I naively do in the 1st example.

I could live with something like this:

```
printf \
  '%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s...' \
    "${a1}" \
    "${a2}" \
    "${a3}" \
    "${a4}" \
    "${a5}" \
    "${a6}" \
    ...
```

although ultimately, for my many variables, I would use a construct like this:

```
${!a*} # or similar
```

Comment: +1 for using vt100-ish terminal setting strings! Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do:

```
printf "^[%s foo" "${a1}" # that is ctrl+v, ESC, followed by %s
```

or:

```
printf "\033%s foo" "${a1}"  # 033 octal for ESC
```

Comment: Sorry, I removed "foo" from my original question as I thought a direct (simple) example would be clearer. If I try your example like this: `printf "^[%s %d\n" "${chosen_colour}" "${score}"`, it does not work..

Comment: @Robottinosino, printf `"\033%s%d\n" "${a1}" "${score}"` works for me

Comment: just want to highlight the double quotes instead of the single quotes

Comment: Here what I run: `s=300;a1="\e[1;33m";a2="${a1}";printf "\e%s %d\n" "${a2}" $s;` -> `e[1;33m 300`

Comment: did you try the two solutions offered above? They work for me. I'm not familiar with a shell that can convert `\e` to the escape character, so don't assume that your's can either. Note the comment about Ctrl-V, Esc  in the first solution. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: are you _sure_ you are running this code in your shell? s=300;a1="\e[1;33m";a2="${a1}";printf "\033%s %d\n" "${a2}" $s;

Comment: I am gonna accept this answer but I think the correct thing to do is rather to just use `%b` as the format string..